# How can I quickly perform a whole-drive dd backup over ssh?

Tags: linux, ssh, backup, dd, administration

I am trying to periodically back up a machine I am hosting remotely with dd. This is the method that I have found works in the past for machines with small drives. But my new machine has a 75 GiB luks-encrypted drive and the script says it is transferring only about 300 KiB/s. I estimate this will take about three full days to complete assuming the connection doesn't drop at some point. How could I speed this up?

```
ssh root@mysite.com dd if="/dev/vda" conv=sync,noerror | gzip -5 - | pv | dd of=whole-drive-bkp-$(date "+%Y%m%d%H%M").dd.gz
```

EDIT: If I pass a block size parameter of 10 megs (`bs=10M`), it increases the rate to closer to 1 MiB/s on average

Comment: Why aren't you using rsync, rsnapshot, or one of the other reliable backup tools? The only thing to say about copying a live system disk with dd is that _if you're fortunate_ you'll notice it's a bad copy sooner rather than later. Do not use dd for copying a disk that's in use

Comment: Related - [Are backups using dd if=/dev/mmcblk0 safe and consistent?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/132886/56994)

Comment: @roaima in practice it's not that bad. I've transferred a dozen of Linux systems like this. However, one really should make sure writes are taken to minimum possible, ideally all file systems remounted as read only before the dump (could be done in e.g. sibling SSH session and undone afterwards), or if LVM is used, better to use snapshots.

Comment: Professional opinion? An unreliable (as in unvalidated, not as in irregular) backup is worse than no backup at all

Comment: get rid of `conv=sync,noerror` as it will either do nothing, or [produce corrupt data](https://superuser.com/a/1075837/195171) while hiding errors from you. it might make more sense to compress it on the sending side, especially if this is a virtual drive where free space is zero after fstrim. then to avoid inconsistency issues, the whole thing should be done from rescue system where the drive is not even mounted at all. for online mirroring, you'd have to use something like RAID or dm-mirror target instead, but no idea how well that would work over a network block device or filesystem.

Comment: with LVM you could make snapshots instead and then transfer the snapshot at your leisure (same with filesystems that support snapshots and the like)

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov Hopefully the 13th you transfer this way either completes as you expect or really isn’t important. I assume you’re also not copying a live transactional database because that will almost certainly fail.

Comment: haha, you're almost right. Some of systems transferred that way are running Oracle Application Servers ;) However, there was LVM and a spare space to have snapshots and I was able to stop the service before taking snapshots, so essentially there was zero chance to become broken. We were transferring that system away from dying BL460c Gen1 server, which finally died the next day after the transfer.

Comment: LVM snapshots can give a frozen filesystem that's safe to copy. However, this isn't a "_whole-drive backup_" - it's a per-LVM volume backup. Very different scenario